# Trying to query and compare two columns from different tables with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to compare two values from two different tables in a filter-query in SQLAlchemy:

```
    response = db.session.query(Building, BuildingTypes)\
    .join(BuildingTypes)\
    .filter(x <= (Building.x+(BuildingTypes.width/2)))\
    .first()
```

My problem is that I always seems to get a response, even when this would result in None. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the class definitions:

```
class BuildingTypes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'buildingTypes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    width = db.Column(db.Integer)
    height = db.Column(db.Integer)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)

class Building(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'buildings'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = db.Column(db.Integer)
    y = db.Column(db.Integer)
    typeID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('buildingTypes.id'))
    buildingTypes = db.relationship("BuildingTypes")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that before the code above, x is retrieved from an request.form statement. And because of that (I suppose) it is not treated like an integer. The solution was therefore to wrap x with int(x) and now the code is working.